Где можно писать на C# в Linux?
Хочу писать на C# в Linux, но не знаю где писать код и компилировать его. Я пробовал в VSCode установил .NET расширения, потом с помощью команд dotnet new cosole сделал проект и запустил его через dotnet run. Но потом возникили другие проблемы и я теперь решил спросить, нет ли других способов. Ну или в крайном случае помочь исправить ошибку, которая возникла в VSCode.

JetBrains => https://www.jetbrains.com/fr-fr/rider/ ?     //// помочь исправить ошибку, которая возникла в VSCode -> это наверно второй/отдельный вопрос.?

@Dev18 да лучше наверное пойду его задам

https://www.mono-project.com/ => https://i.sstatic.net/Yjhbg2hx.png

Emacs => https://stackoverflow.com/q/26334765/13754729

https://www.guru99.com/best-csharp-ide.html

@Dev18 Спасибо я в VSCode почти все настроил осталось найти инфу о том как сделать заупск по кнопке

да, мне самой стало интересно, поставила "отслеживаться" ваш вопрос, и сюда ссылки тоже оставлю, может перейду на линукс, кто знает

@Dev18 Понял. А вы сами на C# пишете?

да, VisualStudio, PreView version (она бесплатная, и круче JetBrains)

vim - лучший выбор! :)

А ещё помните что JetBrains в России больше не работает.

oups...Я не знала, совсем не поддерживается? @чистов_n

@Dev18 https://habr.com/ru/news/655249/
